# Compile-time error when creating a record with postgresql:jsonvalue type in Ballerina

Tags: sql, postgresql, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I’m working on a ballerina project where I’m trying to create a record with the `postgresql:jsonvalue` type to represent the JSON data.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/sql;
import ballerinax/postgresql;

type TestData record {|
    string authId;
    string userId;
    postgresql:JsonValue? data;

public function testFunction(postgresql:Client cl) returns TestData|error {
    TestData queryRow = check cl->queryRow(`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE auth_id = 'authId'`);
    return queryRow;
}
```

When I do this I encounter the following compile time error,

```
incompatible type for parameter 'returnType' with inferred typedesc value: expected 'typedesc<anydata>', found 'typedesc<mindula/testRec:0.1.0:TestData>'
```

However, when I use the normal JSON type, it doesn’t show any compile time errors.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/sql;

type TestData2 record {|
    string authId;
    string userId;
    json? data;
|};

public function testFunction2(postgresql:Client cl) returns TestData2|error {
    TestData2 queryRow = check cl->queryRow(`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE auth_id = 'authId'`);
    return queryRow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compile-time error encountered when using the `postgresql:jsonvalue` type in this record occurs because these special types are introduced primarily for creating `sql:ParameterizedQuery` queries. Unfortunately, Ballerina's `anydata` type doesn't support class variables like `postgresql:JsonValue`. As a result, we get the compilation error.
To resolve this issue and work with JSON data in this record, we can use the second approach with the json type.